# looping through scan and replacing matches individually

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to loop through regex matches and replace each match individually in the loop.

For example:

```
content.scan(/myregex/).each do |m|
  m = 'new str'
end
```

How could I do that?

The reason why I want to do that is because each match will be replaced with a different output from a function.

Thanks for help

Comment: One approach would be to strip off the front of the string after each individual match.

Comment: How much easier that would be compared to other approaches (including mine below) would depend on what the broader objective was. More context might be necessary to derive the "best" option.

Answer (score 6):

The following form of the `gsub` method will do exactly what you want:

```
gsub(pattern) {|match| block } → new_str
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the same thing every time then you could just do:

```
def some_function_here(args)
    .... some logic creates replacement
    while something == true
        content.sub(/myregex/, replacement)
        .... some logic to change replacement/or a call to a helper function
    end
end
```

Not sure how you're generating the new replacement values, but from what I gather it appears that the easiest way to do it is to call the sub method on the string for your regex and replace them one at a time.